# Replace characters in swift 3 string

Tags: string, swift3

I need a function to replace numbers 0..9 with characters A..J consecutively. 
How can I write it in Swift 3?
Swift 3 string manipulation is so weird :|
I tried accessing characters and then adding and offset (shifting) characters, but have no success.

Comment: It would've been helpful to see what you've tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to your problem which is also Unicode safe:

```
let string = "0123456789 abc xyz 9876543210"
// upper case A...J use 65; lower case a...j use 97
let shift = 65
let convertedString = String(string.characters.lazy.map{ char in
    Int(String(char)).map{ Character(UnicodeScalar($0 + shift)!) } ?? char
})
```

## Explanation

### Idea/Problem

Map each character of the string to another (or same) character: 0...9 -> A...J, everything else stays

### Implementation

Use a `lazy` character collection for performance reasons for large strings. A non lazy one would create an intermediate `Array`.

The mapping from one to another character goes through the following process:

1. Try to convert the character to an `Int` (Here `Int?`)

   1.1 If it fails (is `nil`) the nil coalescing operator (`??`) comes in to play and the input character is returned
2. The Int value (`$0`)  now gets converted back to a Character through its (shifted) ASCII representation [image: ASCII Table]
3. Convert the lazily mapped collection to a `String`. Swifts declaration of the initialiser:

   ```
   public init<S : Sequence>(_ characters: S)
       where S.Iterator.Element == Character { ... }
   ```

Comment: Why did you map it with `lazy`? What is the advantage to that?

Comment: @NoahWilder In short: If we don’t use `lazy` we would create an intermediate array of characters which requires a huge amount of memory if the string was long in the first place. See above under **Implementation** for the full explanation.